# Buffer sometimes wrong while received from TCP with boost socket

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, tcp, boost-asio

The problem:
The problem: I have a problem with async_read_some in boost::asio. Sometimes the variable m_deBuff changes inside the callback method TCPSession::handle_read. I can’t figure out why this happens? I’m using a tcp socket on the other side and I have analyzed the data over wireshark and it looks intact. I’m also sending and receiving on the loopback interface 127.0.0.1.

It happens more often when I put std::cout < str; and sleep inside handle_read.

### The code:

```
void TCPSession::start( TCPSessionListner* parent )
{
   std::cout << "TCPSession::started" << std::endl;
   m_parent = parent;

   m_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_deBuff, MAX_LEN),
                            boost::bind(&TCPSession::handle_read, weak_from_this(),
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}


void TCPSession::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
   if (!error)
   {
      m_workingBuffer.insert(m_workingBuffer.end(), m_deBuff, m_deBuff + bytes_transferred);

      if( m_parent != 0 )
      {
         if (false == m_rawRead)
         {
            std::vector< std::string > messages;
            Messages::TcpStreamToMessages(m_workingBuffer, messages);
            m_parent->onData( messages, m_sessionID );
         }

         if (false == m_workingBuffer.empty() && true == m_rawRead)
         {
            std::string str(m_workingBuffer.begin(), m_workingBuffer.end());
            std::cout << str;
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000)); // HERE, while debugging after std::cout m_deBuff has changed (only sometimes)...

            //m_parent->onRawData(m_workingBuffer, m_sessionID);
            m_workingBuffer.clear();
         }
      }

      m_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_deBuff, MAX_LEN),
                               boost::bind(&TCPSession::handle_read, weak_from_this(),
                                           boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                           boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
   }
   else
   {
      if( m_parent != 0 )
      {
         m_parent->onSessionDisconnected( m_sessionID );
      }           
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. 12-space indenting is hard for answerers to read; 2. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) gives answerers more to work with; 3. Use a watchpoint to determine where a variable or memory changes.

Comment: We need enough code to reproduce the problem. Likely it's a threading issue.